# CALL for a procedure keeps loading, takes high CPU, and fails

Tags: mysql, sql, call, explain

I am trying to create a procedure that will take a view table , composed from thousands of records, and will filter it by removing several records according to various conditions.

When I try to use the CALL to run it, it keeps on loading, and according to WHM Panel, the process (phpMyAdmin/import.php) takes about 90% of CPU power.
Eventually it fails perhaps after 10 min due to a timeout:

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25) SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

I'm using the following code, and the new view table is using 3 DB tables:

`vw_r2_items_tr`, is using a `tr` DB core table, and a `vw_items` - a view table which uses `items` and `visits` core tables

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE VIEW `vw_r2_items_tr` AS 
SELECT
  IF((`i`.`id` = `t`.`item_ord`),1,0) AS `has_tr`,
  `i`.`calculated_score`   AS `calculated_score`,
  `i`.`visited_at`         AS `visited_at`,
  `i`.`ip_address`         AS `ip_address`,
  `i`.`user_id`            AS `user_id`,
  `i`.`visit_id`           AS `visit_id`,
  `i`.`product_id`         AS `product_id`,
  `i`.`name`               AS `name`,
  `i`.`id`                 AS `id`,
  `i`.`item_no`            AS `item_no`,
FROM (`vw_items` `i`
   LEFT JOIN `trs` `t`
     ON (((`t`.`visit_id` = `i`.`visit_id`)
          AND (`t`.`item_ord` = `i`.`id`))))$$

DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `vw_unique_trs2`()
BEGIN
SET @vat=0;
SET @ht=0;
SET @tdiff=0;
-- EXPLAIN  
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS ct, 
tb1.* FROM (SELECT it.*, @tdiff:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(it.visited_at,'+00:00',@@global.time_zone)) AS tdiffs,
IF(@vat > 0 AND ((@vat-@tdiff) < 28800 AND (@vat-@tdiff) > -28800),@vat DIV 28800, @tdiff DIV 28800) AS diff,
@ht:=(IF(@vat > 0 AND ((@vat-@tdiff) < 28800  AND (@vat-@tdiff) > -28800),@ht+has_tr,has_tr)) hts,
@vat:=(IF(@vat > 0 AND ((@vat-@tdiff) < 28800 AND (@vat-@tdiff) > -28800),@vat,@tdiff)) curr_vat
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `vw_r2_items_tr` ORDER BY has_tr DESC, item_no, visited_at) AS tb
GROUP BY `tb`.`visit_id`,`tb`.`product_id`) AS it 
ORDER BY has_tr DESC, it.visited_at DESC
) AS tb1
GROUP BY user_id, calculated_score, diff, hts;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: no one has any clue?

Comment: The problem you are having is a bit unclear. What is that quote meant to be? Do you get a syntax error, in addition to the timeout? Why is the error about the syntax quoting code you didn't show us?

Comment: @underscore_d I myself don't really understand. I'm running this from PHPMYADMIN, I simply go to SQL command tab, and type `CALL vw_unique_trs2()' , and then after about 10 minutes of loading, it gives out this error message.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cant use only one "ON" with two join, try to do 2 join query like that

```
    `SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key = Table2.key` and 
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.key = Table2.key`
```